# Error running python code for Interim ERA

Tags: python, weather

I am trying to extract Interim ERA data for specific latitude and longitude values. I am running the python code referenced at https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=73016800

The only thing I have changed is that this code now uses my own csv file of different latitude and longitude values. The format of my csv matches the example given in the code.

When I run the python code, I get the following error:

> ecmwfapi.api.APIException: 'ecmwf.API error 1: ERROR 6 (MARS_EXPECTED_FIELDS): Expected 4, got 0'

Can anyone please advise on the issue?

Comment: Does it succeed with the data provided with the example?

Comment: No, I get the same error with the data provided.